# Why selected data from postmeta table in wordpress, after converting into wordpress date format is always incorrect and Unchanged value?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I used sql query to select my data which is a specific delivery time of an order.Content of data is like (1401/05/31 - 15-2), and the date is based on solar calendar.

```
 $delivery_time = $wpdb->get_var(
                "SELECT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key ='_delivery_time ' and post_id = $order_id");
```

I used explode to split date and time

```
 $data = explode('-', $delivery_time);

 $date = wcdt_convert_number(WC_Delivery_Time_Show::get_date_i18n($data[0]));
 $time = $data[1].'-'.$data[2];
```

The value of $date is always [1348/10/11] and it's wrong
Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: that will never work, you should save dates in mysql fomat or convert them in your query, so that wordpress can use them

Comment: My Query works correctly, it returns the correct value, but the other function which is used to convert date to wordpress format, returns a wrong value

Comment: that is not what i meant 1401/05/31 - 15-2 isn' a valid date anf can not be parsed, so convert the solar date to something gregorian